# Captcha impossible on Safari on iPad1 iOS 5.1.1

Tags: support, captcha

In some cases the captcha asks you to copy some code into a new text box, but there is no way of doing this on an iPad (1).   It is also not possible to request a new captcha as the same paradigm applies to the new one offered. Is there a way around this annoying captcha such that I may contribute to SO and comment on or answer questions?

Due to comment feature also broken, I will add that the copy paste feature in safari does not activate, obviously that is what I tried. Repeatedly.

It seems to be specific to the new type of captcha controls where maybe this iOS 5.1.1 was neglected ?

You might be able to reproduce this captcha by adding an answer with no formatting at all, and the copy code captcha seems to be approximately the third type of captcha after ones like 'select the pictures with road signs' captchas

Comment: That's probably an iOS problem, not an SO problem; I have noticed that, in general, sometimes the selection doesn't always show the action pop-up, and I need to clear the selection and try again.

Comment: Seems to be more a Google captcha style problem to me.  No amount of 'trying again' seemed to help. Will try to clear all caches and see what happens next time.